# How to use transaction in stored procedure of phpmyadmin mysql code?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, phpmyadmin, variable-declaration

I am struggling with declaring a variable with phpmyadmin in stored procedure where in I am storing last_insert_id value of each table in different parameter.

I need your guidance in following questions

1)How can I store LAST_INSERT_ID in 3 variables and insert them in 4th table.
2)How to declare a variable in phpmyadmin and what to put in definition section of Add routine 
3)How to use semi colon for each sentence?

So, **what to put in definition of Add routine.**....

Here is my code......

```
USE `videogame_collection_1`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sp_Add_Game`;

  DELIMITER $$
 USE `videogame_collection_1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Add_Game` (IN Game_Name_ip VARCHAR(100),IN Genre_ip   ENUM('Controllers', 'Extreme Sports', 'Action & Adventure', 'Racing', 'RPG',   'Baseball', 'Sports', 'Systems', 'Puzzle', 'Fighting', 'Strategy', 'FPS',   'Wrestling', 'Accessories', 'Soccer', 'Other', 'Football', 'Party', 'Arcade',   'Basketball', 'Simulation', 'Music'),
  IN Rating_ip ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),IN Platform_Name_ip ENUM('N64',    'NES', 'Super Nintendo', 'Gamecube', 'Wii', 'Playstation 1', 'Playstation 2',   'Playstation 3', 'Xbox', 'Xbox 360', 'Sega Genesis', 'Atari 2600', 'Gameboy   Color', 'Gameboy Advance'),IN Completeness_Type_ip ENUM('B', 'I', 'C', 'BC',   'BI', 'IC', 'BIC'), IN Condition_ip ENUM('New', 'Mint', 'Very Good', 'Good',    'Acceptable', 'Poor'),
   IN Purchase_Date_ip DATE,IN Purchase_Price_ip DECIMAL(4,2))
   BEGIN
  DECLARE Game_key int;
    DECLARE MyCollection_Key int;
    DECLARE Platform_Key int;
     START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.video_game(`Game_Name`, `Genre`,  `Rating`) VALUES (Game_Name_ip, Genre_ip,Rating_ip);
             SET Game_key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
     INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.mycollection (`Completeness_Type`,  `Condition`, `Purchase_Date`, `Purchase_Price`) VALUES (Completeness_Type_ip,  Condition_ip, Purchase_Date_ip, Purchase_Price_ip);
         SET MyCollection_Key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.platform(`Platform_Name`) VALUES   (Platform_Name_ip);
          SET Platform_Key = LAST_INSERT_ID();
          INSERT INTO    videogame_collection_1.video_game_platform_mycollection(`MyCollection_Id`,    `Game_Id`, `Platform_Id`) VALUES (MyCollection_Key,Game_key,Platform_Key);
      INSERT INTO videogame_collection_1.Trend( `Game_Id`,    `Market_Price`,`Capture_Date`) VALUES    (Game_key,Purchase_Price_ip,Purchase_Date_ip);
        COMMIT;
         END
       $$
         DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 1)I tried putting declaration in transactions 2) instead of setting variables with key, I tried select LAST_INSERT_ID into @game_key 3) I removed all delimeters 4) I removed transaction, commit and end 5)  I  put NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER  and 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  at appropriate location. But, it still not result in success

Comment: How did you try and what was the error you encountered?

Comment: I have tried in phpmyadmin add routine. I got Error code:1064  on declare keyword. I also got same error in set and start transaction

Comment: So, you got syntax errors. Update your question with what you have tried and we will help you correct it

Comment: I corrected all syntax error. I just need the guidance on where I am making mistakes in a code